# IPython doesn't echo code input

Tags: python, ipython

Typically when I send code from a Python script using C-c C-e to IPython, IPython does not echo the code that I input. For example, sending a script with just the following in `test.py`

```
2 + 2
```

and running it via C-c C-e will result in the following:

```
In [1]:
Out[1]: 4
```

Occassionally, it'll result in the following:

```
In [1]:
__PYTHON_EL_eval("2 + 2", "/Users/cdesjardins/foo.py")
Out[1]: 4
```

I would prefer that IPython always echos my input. Ideally, just saying:

```
In [1]: 2 + 2
Out[1]: 4
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this. I am using `eglot` and `pylsp` but when I disable `eglot` I am still getting this issue.

Comment: AFAICT, there is no provision for that: you get a message of the string sent in the echo area, but it is not inserted into the `*Python*` buffer. You'd need to change the code in `python-shell-send-string` so that the string is inserted in the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a somewhat 'intricate' problem. The problem is that Emacs uses `python-shell-send-string` to retrieve all kinds of information from the interactive shell in the background. One of the 'required' configurations to make this work correctly, is to start ipython with the `--simple-prompt` argument. But when starting ipython like this, input is no longer inserted (displayed) into the shell when using `process-send-string`. However, starting ipython without the argument, breaks the 'information retrieval functionality'. So, that is no option either.

Now, starting ipython without the `--simple-prompt` argument won't work, neither will changing (in some straightforward way) the `python-shell-send-string` function.

So then, I guess, the most straightforward solution is to create a custom command that simply copies the 'statement' to the ipython shell buffer, and then sends it from there. Starting from the `python-shell-send-statement` function, we could come up with a most basic 'custom' command that looks as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-python-shell-send-statement ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((region (if (region-active-p)
                     (cons (region-beginning) (region-end))
                   (cons
                    (save-excursion (python-nav-beginning-of-statement))
                    (save-excursion (python-nav-end-of-statement)))))
         (string (buffer-substring (car region) (cdr region))))
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer (python-shell-get-process-or-error))
      (insert string)
      (comint-send-input))))
```

The above command can be used at least for sending single line statements. It can also be used for sending simple regions, but I guess it will break for more complex regions (although it might also just work for those).

Similarly, we could create 'custom' versions of the other `python-shell-send-...` functions, although it might take some extra work to get the strings formatted correctly in the ipython shell buffer (also the code above might work fine enough already; I have not tested it thoroughly).

This would be my first 'naive' approach, and it seems to work fine, at least for 'single line' statements. You can try the above command by evaluating it and using it via `M-x` or by binding it to your preferred key.

Comment: This sounds very sensible, but I also have this issue on Mac OS X and I did not have this issue in the past. I'm surprised to find so few questions and solutions for this issue if it was this general.

Comment: Actually starting ipython without the `--simple-prompt` argument removed the annoying `__PYTHON_EL_eval` but inputs were still not echo'ed. I then reverted to using `elpy` which I had been using in the past and used
`(setq elpy-shell-echo-output t)
    (setq elpy-shell-echo-input t)
    (setq elpy-shell-add-to-shell-history t)`
and this works as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fixed you are on using `ipython`, but I have found a way to display the input properly for `python` shells without using elpy (as I use LSP over elpy): https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495202/13029473

Hope this helps you find a solution that works for you as well.

Comment: In your link posted, you have a mistake - the second function should be ```dn/.....```.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I fixed it now.